# What does it mean for .slice() to be a "shallow clone"?

Tags: arrays, actionscript, vector, slice, shallow-copy

ActionScript's Array and Vector classes both have a slice() method. If you don't pass any parameters, the new Array or Vector is a duplicate (shallow clone) of the original Vector.

What does it mean to be a "shallow clone"? Specifically, what is the difference between

```
Array newArray = oldArray.slice();
Vector.<Foo> newVector = oldVector.slice();
```

and

```
Array newArray = oldArray;
Vector.<Foo> newVector = oldVector;
```

? Also, what if the Vector's base type isn't Foo, but something simple and immutable like int?

**Update:**

What is the result of the following?

```
var one:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>()

one.push("something");
one.push("something else");

var two:Vector.<String> = one.slice();

one.push("and another thing");

two.push("and the last thing");

trace(one); // something, something else, and another thing
trace(two); // something, something else, and the last thing
```

Thanks! ♥

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your context, what `.slice()` does is simply to make a copy of your vector, so that `newArray` refers to a different object from `oldArray`, except both seem like identical objects. Likewise goes for `newVector` and `oldVector`.

The second snippet:

```
Array newArray = oldArray;
Vector.<Foo> newVector = oldVector;
```

actually makes `newArray` a *reference* to `oldArray`. That means both variables refer to the same array. Same for `newVector` and `oldVector` — both end up referring to the same vector. Think of it as using a rubber stamp to stamp the same seal twice on different pieces of paper: it's the same seal, just represented on two pieces of paper.

On a side note, the term **shallow copy** differs from **deep copy** in that shallow is a copy of *only the object* while deep is a copy of the *object and all its properties*.

> Also, what if the Vector's base type isn't Foo, but something simple and immutable like int?

It's the same, because your variables refer to the `Vector` objects and not their `int`s.

> What is the result of the following?

Your output is correct:

```
something, something else, and another thing
something, something else, and the last thing
```

`two = one.slice()`, without any arguments, makes a new copy of `one` with all its current contents and assigns it to `two`. When you push each third item to `one` and `two`, you're appending to distinct `Vector` objects.

Comment: You mean the contents of `oldArray` and `newArray` are identical Objects, but the references are distinct?

Comment: @Svetlana: The objects represented by `oldArray` and `newArray` when you `.slice()` it are different, but the references of their properties may differ if they are non-primitive types. If you simply assign one to the other, both are distinct references to the same object.